# nth element of <a> tag according to the URL

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I am using the selenium firefox plugin and run across an issue of trying to select the nth element of multiple  tags with the same value of the href attribute but just having the id at the last change.

After looking at the screenshot the argument:

```
//a[contains(@href, '/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/')]
```

must be the 2nd element I tried:

```
//a[contains(@href, '/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/')][2]
```

and got an error in the log:

[error] Element //a[contains(@href, '/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/')][2] not found
[image: Selenium IDE on firefox]

Here is the HTML sample:

```
<table class="table table-bordered ">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <td class="col-md-10">Goal</td>
     <td class="col-md-2 text-center">Actions</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>
        FF_selenium_test                    
     </td>
     <td class="text-center">
        <a href="/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/3" data-toggle="ajaxModal" class="btn btn-block " title="Edit">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Edit                            </a>
        <a href="/setup/goal_delete/Orm_Institution/1/3" data-toggle="deleteAction" message="Are you sure ?" class="btn btn-block " title="Delete">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Delete                            </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        FF_selenium for editing                    
     </td>
     <td class="text-center">
        <a href="/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/4" data-toggle="ajaxModal" class="btn btn-block " title="Edit">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Edit                            </a>
        <a href="/setup/goal_delete/Orm_Institution/1/4" data-toggle="deleteAction" message="Are you sure ?" class="btn btn-block " title="Delete">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Delete                            </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have clicked the find button to test it using [2] and [1] but was not successful in defining the index. I have done a workaround by moving out to the parent then defining the child by appending " /::descendant" at the end. although this works I don't seem fully satisfied as I feel there is a need to use the index in combination with @contains for the attribute.

Comment: I found another workaround by finding the sibling in another instance... as such:

//td[text()[contains(.,'selenium delete me (edited)')]]/following-sibling::td[@class='text-center']/descendant::a[contains(@href, '/semester/delete/')]

I am still interested to find the index solution though :)

Comment: Share `HTML` sample for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your specific environment, but I think your code should work... Try to place paranthesis around your `XPath` before the `[2]`

Some possible issues:

- case sensitivity
- namespaces (don't think so in your case)
- The existing HTML you test against doesn't have a second `<a>` with this `href` value
- Due to previous steps the current node is not the root. Searching with `//a` will not find higher occurances if your current node is somewhere done the path...

Try it like this:

```
(//a[@href='/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/'])[2]
```

This should find all `<a>` elements, where the `href`-attribute has the given value. Then it takes the second occurance...

Tested with SQL-Server, but should be similar in your environment:

```
DECLARE @ITEM XML=
N'<html>
  <body>
  <a href="YourURL">Test1</a>
  <SomeOther><inner><a href="YourURL">Testinner</a></inner></SomeOther>
  <a href="YourURL">Test2</a>
  <a href="YourURL">Test3</a>
  </body>   
  </html>';
```

--Works for all

```
SELECT @ITEM.value('(//*[local-name()="a" and @href="YourURL"]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)');
```

--better, only looking for `<a>`

```
SELECT @ITEM.value('(//a[@href="YourURL"]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)');
```

--returns `NULL`, there is no *second* `<a>` **below** `<SomeOther>`
--But with `[1]` it would return the same as the above...

```
SELECT @ITEM.query('/html/body/SomeOther').value('(//a[@href="YourURL"])[2]','nvarchar(max)');
```

### UPDATE: Use your given sample

Tried it again with your given sample. Works here (SQL Server), should work with you too...

```
DECLARE @ITEM XML=
N'<table class="table table-bordered ">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <td class="col-md-10">Goal</td>
     <td class="col-md-2 text-center">Actions</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>
        FF_selenium_test                    
     </td>
     <td class="text-center">
        <a href="/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/3" data-toggle="ajaxModal" class="btn btn-block " title="Edit">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Edit                            </a>
        <a href="/setup/goal_delete/Orm_Institution/1/3" data-toggle="deleteAction" message="Are you sure ?" class="btn btn-block " title="Delete">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Delete                            </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        FF_selenium for editing                    
     </td>
     <td class="text-center">
        <a href="/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/4" data-toggle="ajaxModal" class="btn btn-block " title="Edit">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Edit                            </a>
        <a href="/setup/goal_delete/Orm_Institution/1/4" data-toggle="deleteAction" message="Are you sure ?" class="btn btn-block " title="Delete">
        <span class="btn-label-icon left fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Delete                            </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>';
```

--Both attempts return "Edit"

```
SELECT @ITEM.value('(//*[local-name()="a" and contains(@href, "/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/")]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)');

SELECT @ITEM.value('(//a[contains(@href, "/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/")]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)');
```

Comment: Shnugo, I tried it like you suggested and got:

    [error] locator not found: (//a[contains(@href, '/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/')])[2]

    [error] locator not found: (//a[contains(@href, '/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/')])[1]

    [error] locator not found: (//a[contains(@href, '/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/')])[0]

Comment: @AzaamAlfi-PSM I tested this [on this online `XPath` tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) and it worked as expected...

Comment: I tried it again: [error] locator not found: (//a[contains(@href, '/setup/goal_add_edit/Orm_Institution/1/')]/text())[1].... I would give you a rate up but I need 15 points to do sow :)

Comment: @AzaamAlfi-PSM You just crossed the 15 points border... :-D Did you check this `XPath` in another context? This should work...

Comment: By "context" I assume you mean other then the "Selenium IDE" firefox plugin because you used the MS SQL... I only have the plugin to work with and have tried 2 workarounds that don't seem to solve the problem directly.

Comment: @AzaamAlfi-PSM Yes, that's what I meant... Tried with online tests? I've placed a link which worked fine...

Comment: it works on the link you provided... but don't know why its not working on the  original site :(

I will accept the answer though